# How to Get json data in one another page?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want to view per user into other page.
How to get user json data using ajax?

```
"users": [
{
    {
        "id": "01",
        "name": "Joseph",
        "age": "20",
    },
    {
        "id": "02",
        "name": "Christ",
        "age": "20"
    }
}]



<a href="view.html?id=01"> View Josepth </a>
<a href="view.html?id=02"> View Christ </a>
```

Comment: Needs more information, where are you fetching the data from? 
Is it hardcoded in a script? Is it depending on the id in the URL that you want to fetch it from a service?

Comment: depending on the url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385578/how-to-get-user-profile-information-from-json-api-using-jquery

Comment: i saw it but only on one page

Comment: i have index file, view file and data.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you would get the id of the user from the URL (you can use the [URL Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)) and then depending on how your server is exposing the endpoint you call it using `window.prototype.fetch` ([Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)) like so:

```js
(async function() {
  const url = new URL("http://view.html?id=02");

  const { searchParams } = url;

  const userId = searchParams.get("id");

  const userData = await fetch(`https://yourapi.com/user/${userId}`);

  console.log(userData);
})()
```

Hope it helps, notice that since you didnt provide me with information on how to request this data (how does the server that provides data exposes its data - its API) I just wildly guessed you send a `GET` with the user id as query params.

Since you already told me above that you have a `data.json` all you need is to get the user id from the URL and then filter the parsed json like so:

```
const data = JSON.parse(require('./data.json'));

const url = new URL("http://view.html?id=02");

const { searchParams } = url;

const userId = searchParams.get("id");

const userData = data.filter((user) => user.id === userId);

// here you should see the object with the data for that specific user Id
console.log(userData);
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding your problem correctly but I don't see the need of using ajax if you already have the data you need in `data.json`.